# How to append resource streams in Scala from a file path list?

Tags: list, scala, inputstream

**This works pretty well for a single file**

```
val inputSteamFromFile  = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/file1")
val inputStreamAsString : Array[String] = scala.io.Source
.fromInputStream(inputSteamFromFile)
.mkString.split(",")
.filter(queryStr => queryStr.trim.length != 0)
```

**But if i want to the same for multiple files say**

```
filePathList =  ["/File1",  "/File2"] the following is not wrorking!

val inputStreamAsString : Array[String] = filePathList
.foreach(
files => scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream(files))
.mkString.split(",")
.filter(queryStr => queryStr.trim.length != 0)
)
```

Comment: replace `foreach` with a `flatMap`

Comment: Oh yes my bad! It's a function calling another.